# Index entry to suggest looking at another

Tags: indexing

I tried looking around for solutions, to what I thought would be simple, but I can't really find the answer.

I am using `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and I want to add some entries that are in the format of "Term1, see Term2" (i.e. "Python, see Language!Python") as a way to help the reader when there are terms that they might look for instead of those provided. Something like an `\indexref{Term1}{Term2}`.

Comment: I think that at minimum bib2gls should be able to do that by keyword "see." If switching to bib2gls is an option for you, look at the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Makeindex` then in your source
`\index{Alfabet|see{Bet}}`

will produce an index entry like: Alfabet *see* Bet

I have never used the `imakeidx` package, perhaps the above will also work with it.